# Image covering Form in Mobile Site

Tags: css, image, forms, z-index

I have a responsive site that has an image next to a form. My problem is that when the screen shrinks the image covers the form. I would like it so that the form covers the image. I have tried changing the Z-Index but it doesn't seem to work. You can see examples of my problem here: http://inventivewebdesign.com/uctest/?page_id=45

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Ok, I am on my mobile device and i notice in your div and your image that an active attribute is `float:left;` Try also applying a `position:relative;` and let me know. I don't have a console on my mobile device.

Comment: Or rather, try it for yourself and see if it helps. If not, send me a response and I'll see what else I can do. @MattM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at it and just used CSS to make the specific div for this specific page to change the width when the screen shrinks, works fine now. Thanks for your ideas.